# Does this LINQ query call the database on each filter?

Tags: linq, filter

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = (from x in db.Employees
                            where x.FirstName.Contains(textBox1.Text)
                            select x);
```

I am using the above expression in my `txtSearch_TextChanged` event to filter the results real time. Does this call the Database every time a key is pressed to get the results OR are the results cached in the memory in some way and filtered and returned? Is this is the correct way of doing some real time filter like this in LINQ?

```
Northwind db = new Northwind(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");


private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.DataSource = (from x in db.Employees
                                    where x.FirstName.Contains(textBox1.Text)
                                    select x);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... if you call that every time a key is pressed, the database is being queried every time a key is pressed.

But it's worse than that - LINQ is having to compile that expression into SQL every time, and that's a significant amount of work, too.

So no - that is not the correct way to do it. You should cache the data on the client first to do the auto complete... or at least only start pulling (and then cache) after two characters or so, so you can limit the results to cache.

Comment: What kind of cache are we talking about here? Would a DataTable suffice for the requirements?

Comment: That could work, but it may be too 'heavy'; perhaps something as simple as a `List<string>`, each value being those which start with the letter(s) that started the user's entry. Then on each key press, you can instead first check to make sure they haven't backspaced beyond the first letter(s), and if not, update the autocomplete list with the appropriate values which are a match to what they've typed in so far.